# How to calculate the length orthogonal projection of a point onto a line

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say you have point A, B, C, these are represented by vectors:

($x_a$, $y_a$), ($x_c$, $y_c$), ($x_c$, $y_c$)

Imagine you draw a line across B and C, how do I find the length of the orthogonal projection of A to the line represented by B,C

[image]

I know how to calculate the orthogonal projection of 2 vectors (Which I learned in undergrad linear algebra). But I don't think I learned how to project a vector onto a line that is formed by 2 vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line whose length you have labeled as "$?$" is the vector $\overrightarrow{AB}-\text{proj}_{\overrightarrow{BC}}(\overrightarrow{AB})$. So if you can calculate the projection of one vector onto another, then you can calculate the length of that line.

Comment: Is vector AB = A - B? God I am so stupid. Sorry this seems really obvious now

Comment: No, $\overrightarrow{AB}= B-A$.

Comment: I have marked it as the correct answer. I don't know how to face my linear algebra teacher. Thank you very much for helping me

Comment: Actually does the direction of the vector even matter? like vector AB vs vector BA. The length of projection should be same regardless of which direction no?

Comment: You're right, the length will be the same whether you use $\overrightarrow{AB}$ or $\overrightarrow{BA}$. However, you can't do, for instance, $\overrightarrow{AB}-\text{proj}_{\overrightarrow{BC}}(\overrightarrow{BA})$. You have to be consistent.

Comment: @samol - don't be too hard on yourself.